# Finding the identity and invertible elements of the set of multiples of $3$ until $42$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

We have the following question for the homework.

Consider the set $S = \{ 0, 3, \ldots, 39 \}$ of multiples of $3$ in $\Bbb Z_{42}$. Find the identity of $S$ under multiplication, modulo $42$. Determine the invertible elements in $S$ under multiplication, modulo $42$.Any thoughts on how to solve this? I know that for an identity element,

$a \ast e = a= e \ast a$ , but how can I take this further?

I know there is a way using tables ([as shown here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Ebshipley/soln.hw3.330.pdf)), but this approach would take too long with a big set like the one we've been given. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

I was able to get the identity element (15) with modular arithmetic, but how can I find the invertible elements. We know that we can make a table for determining this, but that process would be long and messy for bigger numbers. Is there a mathematical way that does not rely on the tables?

[image]

Comment: The table approach is quick if you do it in a spreadsheet.  Use mixed references (fixed in one axis and relative in the other) and you can write the formula once, then copy right and down.  For a small table like this you can then just find the identity by inspection.  I would do a few hundred elements this way.

Comment: Alternately, use $e^2 \equiv e, e(e-1)\equiv 0 \pmod {42}$  You know $e$ will have a factor $3$, but you need factors $2,7$ still.

Comment: @RossMillikan $e^2 \equiv e$ is a necessary, but not sufficient, condition for the identity. EG $ e \equiv 21$ works, but $ 3 \times 21 \equiv 21 \neq 3 \pmod{42}$.   $\quad$ Instead, if we let $ a \equiv 3$, then $ 3 e \equiv 3 \pmod{42} $ has a unique solution. We then need to verify that it is truly an identity.

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty clear that if $3e\equiv3\pmod{42}$ then also $6e\equiv6\pmod{42}$ and so on.  Therefore you only have to solve the first equation to give $e\equiv1\pmod{14}$.  Since you also know that $e$ is a multiple of $3$, this gives a unique solution for $e$.

(And of course if $3e\not\equiv3\pmod{42}$ then $e$ is not an identity anyway.)